# Using DbFunctions methods without installing Entity Framework nuget

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, dbfunctions

I have a three tier ASP.Net Web application. The Data Layer has reference to EF and it contains all the repositories too. So I have installed EF nuget there.

Then I have a service layer to transfer data to and from data layer to views. Issue is, recently I came across a requirement where I need to use `DbFunctions.AddDays` but I don't want to install the complete EF in service layer for a single query. Is there any way I can achieve the same without installing EF i.e. any other way to achieve the same without using `DbFunctions`. Query is:

```
Context.Article.Where(p => EntityFunctions.AddDays(p.StartDate, p.Period) > DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: No actually, I am writing queries in service layer without any issues. I just discovered that for some weird reason, we have a special method to compare dates and that special method resides in EF dll. No clue why `Date.AddDays()` does not work

Answer (score 1):

> we have a special method to compare dates and that special method resides in EF dll. No clue why Date.AddDays() does not work

No good reason.  This was enabled in [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/index), which runs on [.NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/full-dotnet/) as well as [.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/).  EG:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;


namespace EfCoreTest
{

    public class Article
    {
        [Key]
        public int ArticleId { get; set; }
        public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public int Period { get; set; }
    }
    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        readonly string connectionString;

        public Db(): this("server=.;database=EfCoreTest;Integrated Security=true")
        {

        }
        public Db(string connectionString)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
        }
        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }



    class Program
    {



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();
                var r = db.Articles.Where(p => p.StartDate.AddDays(p.Period) < DateTime.Now).ToList();

            }

            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}
```

translates to

```
SELECT [p].[ArticleId], [p].[ArticleTitle], [p].[Period], [p].[StartDate]
FROM [Articles] AS [p]
WHERE DATEADD(day, [p].[Period], [p].[StartDate]) < GETDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks actually I am already mid-way a project and cannot switch to  EF Core, but for future I will keep this in mind.